# how to add css loader in webpack in react js latest version

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to edit `webpack.confing.js` file but i get failed error.

```
test: cssRegex,
              exclude: cssModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders({
                importLoaders: 1,
                modules: true,
                localIdentName:'[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]',
                sourceMap: isEnvProduction
                  ? shouldUseSourceMap
                  : isEnvDevelopment,
              }),
```

After start it will happend.

> Failed to compile
> ./src/index.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-4-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/index.css)
> ValidationError: Invalid options object. CSS Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
>
> - options has an unknown property 'localIdentName'. These properties are valid:
>   object { url?, import?, modules?, icss?, sourceMap?, importLoaders?, esModule? }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try**

```
test: cssRegex,
              exclude: cssModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders({
                importLoaders: 1,
                modules: {
                  //mode:'local',
                  localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
                },
                
                sourceMap: isEnvProduction
                  ? shouldUseSourceMap
                  : isEnvDevelopment,
```